# Verify if my yii 1.1.x project is PSR-2

Tags: php, yii, psr-2

If yii 1.1.x support PSR-2 ? I mean original framework?
If there is some tool to verify if my yii 1.1.x project(or just php project) corresponds to 
PSR-2 ?I am tring to write in PSR-2, but old habits are difficult to overcome...

Answer (score 1):

Yii does not fully follow PSR-2, there are some differences. You can find the Yii (1) coding style guide [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/wiki/Core-framework-code-style) and PSR-2 [here](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md).

However you can write your applications code in whatever style you prefer. If you want it to be PSR-2 compatible, the easiest would be to install [CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) and set the standard to PSR-2 and check your code.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
CodeSniffer is great! 
Also in my yii 1.1.15 I constantly get error at the header of file
"Each class must be in a namespace of at least one level (a top-level vendor name)"

If there is a way to remove this message as yii 1.1 does not work with namespaces ?
Also how can I configure params of verification : say PSR2 standart now is no more 120 symbolls is 1 line. I neglect this as I have big 23 inches
 monitor : how can I for validation set this parameter to 180?

Comment: As said Yii is not fully PSR-2, and yes Yii 1.1 does not use namespaces. There is a codesniffer standard for yii which you can find above over the link to it's coding style guide. But note that there is not much of a point to validate the frameworks code itself.
Params might be configurable in the ruleset.xml. You can configure the 120 char limit if you open the ruleset.xml of PSR2 standard. But I don't recommend editing this file, it would be better to create your own standard and overwrite this rule there.